# What connector pin header can I use for high voltage?

Tags: pcb-design, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage

I am making a PCB for a double pulse test setup. What connector pin can I use on my PCB to connect a high voltage DC supply for the HV+ and HV- connections?

Voltage ratings: 100VDC and 800VDC.

The operating current on the PCB is around 30 A.

Comment: Yes @RohatKılıç

Comment: High voltage usually uses SHV connectors. These don't come in PCB mount versions; you'll need to mount them to the case.

Answer (score 4):

A quick [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/) parametric search

**(1)** *"Connector" -> "Circular Connectors" -> "Circular Connector Assemblys" ->*

**(2)** *Max. Current >= 30A -> Max. Voltage >= 800V*

yields [This connector](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/chogori-technologies-inc/901-03086-00/16672563)

[image]

and

[image]

[this plug](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/chogori-technologies-inc/901-03087-00/16672553) as possible options. Different colors are available.

**NOTE:**

Don't get this wrong, but if you have to ask how to find such connectors, you should stay away from HV and especially HV/HI DC applications.

Far away.

Really far.